# Why session.invalidate doesn't work in IE browser?

Tags: java, session, servlets, servlet-filters

I implemented a sevlet filter in my application, and within the filter, if I find some specific url pattern, I will use request.getSession().invalidate() to logout and clear the session, then redirect to a login page.

```
session.invalidate();
session.setAttribute("hi", true);
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

but I found, after that I enter username and password, then submit the login form, the previous session seems not be completely cleared.

So is it possible to let me completely clear out the session and just like start a new IE instance ?(BTY, my code works in FF and Chrome).

Comment: how can you say that its not working for IE? I mean what made you to register that its not working for IE

Comment: for example:  If I use a new IE instance, after I submit the login form, the request won't contain "Authorization header", but if it is the case I described above, then in the request it will contain a "Authorization header" which must due to the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is a server-side concept. The browser only hold a jsessionid to tell the server which session object to fetch for this request.

That said, your problem is not IE. And even if it is, it is some sort of caching the you are facing. Clear your cache. You can set these response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
```

Comment: I know this too, but the problem is I can not clear the cache at server side.

Comment: yeah, it's client side cache, I can not clear client-side cache at server side, and it's ridiculous to ask the user to clear the cache after logout, right ?

Comment: you can send headers that instruct the browser not to cache. See updated

Comment: I tried, but not work ... Could you please have a look at my comment under my question , that is the more specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Bozho a quick question to clarify. JSP has default session implict object created. Here in this case ,he created a session and then invalidates , after invalidation , he sets the attributes  which again uses implicit session created.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post.
But recently I have the same problem.

I try session.invalidate().... and not works.
I try delete coockies and not works...

The problem was internet explorer cache.. I just put no cache headers on my serlevt response and then works for me.

Exmple code:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //HTTP 1.1 
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
    ......
    ......
    response.response.getWriter().print(json);
```

}